# Variable name as a string data member

Tags: c++, metadata, c-preprocessor, stringification

In C++ is it possible to declare a class which has a `private std::string` data member which is initialized with the stringized / stringified name of the instance symbol name?  I can see that this couldn't work for temporaries, but for lvalues is it possible?

Here is what I would like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class symbol {
 public:
  symbol() { // here goes some magical sauce }
  void print() { std::cout << s_ << std::endl; }
 private:
  std::string s_;
};

int main() {
  symbol bar, bah;
  bar.print()  // should print "bar" to STDOUT
  bah.print()  // should print "bah" to STDOUT
}
```

If I were to change the constructor to accept a string and introduce a preprocessor macro, then I can almost get what I want, but it smells bad.

```
#define makesymbol(x) foo x(#x)
symbol(const std::string & s) : s_(s) {}

// Now I can do:
makesymbol(test);
test.print();  // <--- This prints "test" followed by a newline to STDOUT
```

Basically what I would like to avoid is for the user to have to declare instances of symbols like:

```
symbol phi("phi");
```

Because it is annoying to read, annoying to type, and redundant.  I can see why in some cases you might want a different string stored than the variable name, but I'm specifically trying to the solve the problem where you know you want the string to be equal to the stringized variable name.

Comment: No, this is not possible without your extra macro, and many (dare I say most) variables have no name. This is what a debugger is for.

Comment: @Pubby I want this because if I build a symbol class that allows mathematical operations, I would like to be able to generate code which has the same variable names as in my original source code.  Also, I want it because as I mentioned, `symbol phi("phi");` means you are typing phi twice and you have to remember to change both -- a source of bugs for users.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I know how to use a debugger but this doesn't solve my problem, which is having the variable name embedded in each instance as meta-data so that code output is possible with the same variable names as was used in the original source.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not possible in C++. The best you can do is your macro. And writing the question multiple times will not help.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Thanks for pointing out the duplicate, I know that writing the question multiple times will not help.  I made a mistake because I closed my browser and thought I hadn't submitted.  I have deleted the other question.